# Is there a way to click a link only once using greasemonkey?

Tags: click, greasemonkey

Is there a way to click a link only once using Greasemonkey?
Script is (e.g.):

```
var evt = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
document.getElementById('DailyConsumtionTrigger').dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: Only once per how often?  How does the script know a start from when to stop?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Well, I don't know, so I asked you and other people here.

Comment: It's the whole script, only it doesn't have Timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the click is just time based (EG every 12 hours) then something like this will work:

```
var intervalInMillisecs = 12 * 3600 * 1000; //-- 12 hours
var currentDateTime     = new Date ();
currentDateTime         = currentDateTime.valueOf ();   //-- Raw mS

//--- Get last click time, if it was set.
var lastClickTime       = GM_getValue ('lastClickTime_DCT');
if (!lastClickTime)
    lastClickTime       = 0;


//--- If this is the first ever run or the interval has past, click the button.
if ( currentDateTime - lastClickTime  >  intervalInMillisecs )
{
    GM_setValue ('lastClickTime_DCT', currentDateTime);

    var evt             = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    document.getElementById ('DailyConsumtionTrigger').dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```

Note that [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) stores information semi-permanently, per script.

If the click is *state* or *event* based (EG Only click when gauge X nears zero), then test for the appropriate condition instead.

### IMPORTANT:

The above was based on the stated question of "clicking only once".
It assumes that the user will be browsing the target (game) site frequently and doesn't want to over trigger the target button across page loads.

To trigger repeatedly, use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval);

Comment: Thank you! But, if I wanted that the interval is every 4 seconds, I change     var intervalInMillisecs = 12 * 3600 * 1000; into var intervalInMillisecs = 4000 ?

Comment: Yes, 4000 would be 4 seconds.  **BUT**, THAT's a different problem from what you asked!   The link was to be clicked only once, not once every 4 seconds.  Do you need to edit your question?

Comment: I have a problem and there are two solutions to this problem: either to click the link only once or to click the link in time interval of 4 seconds.

Comment: @Brock Adams, it won't click a link. I copied The exact same script that you answered.

Comment: Ok, but we cannot know what the problem is other than by what you state in the question.  "Clicking once" is almost the polar opposite of "click every 4 seconds".  They are two different questions and problems.

Comment: O.K., sorry for misunderstanding with my question.

Comment: I looked at Error Console and it shows this Error: Permission denied for <http://ads.contentabc.com> to call method Location.toString

Comment: `"it won't click a link."` -- The code design works, although I haven't yet tested my exact answer. (I'm going offline in a minute). ... Remember that this current answer only fires once.  To get a second firing both (A) the interval must have passed and (B) you must reload or revisit the page. ... Open `about:config` in Firefox. Filter on ***lastClickTime***.  Is there a value?

Comment: That Error has nothing to do with the GM script, unless the `// @include` directive is mis-set.  Update your question with the full, unedited GM script you are testing. ...  Also, sounds like you need to install the [Adblock plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) add-on!

Comment: Script works excellent with setInterval(); , I didn't see it earlier :D. Thanks for your time!